# Angular self-signed certificate, proxy error

Tags: angular, https

My Angular app always worked correctly. I have a connection to my REST service and I set the url in my proxy.conf.json file:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://myurl:myport",
        "secure": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

I am now working from my house and the REST service has moved from the backend developer under https connection. I tried this new `https://mysafeurl:mynewport` under Postman and all works perfectly. But I tried to change the URL in my conf file and I see the following error. How can I solve the problem?

Under Visual Studio Code console:

> Error occurred while trying to proxy request rest_service_name from localhost:4200 to https://newurl (EPROTO) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

Under browser developer console:

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url:

### Edit

Error screen:

[image]

Comment: Is it a typo `"target": "http` ? there is no https? also please post the whole `HttpErrorResponse`

Comment: First, thank for your time. Yes, this is the old connection, not safe, which worked (the secure:true is an error, I correct immediately. The new one has https. And now I send you also the error..

Comment: Aready edited original question with the error screen. Thank.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem and I have a 421 error (Misdirected request) when trying to proxy to a https self signed certificate URL, with `"secure": false`. Do you have this as well ?

Comment: Mmm no, with secure true I see 500. Evereycase thank you very much for your time and for reproducing, I think we can now see the same situation and we are in the near of solution! If you need other info let me know!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
{
"/api/": {
"target": {
"host": "mylink",
"protocol": "https:",
"port": myport
},
"secure": false,
"changeOrigin": true,
"logLevel": "info"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `secure` to `false`, then the certificate won't be verified.

Comment: No, the once problem is (as already told) the connection. In Postman it works; in Angular, the old link (identic but not https) has alway worked.